Complexity of multivariate polynomial division (by a Gröbner basis, say)
All polynomials in this question are over $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$. Given a list of polynomials $f_1, \dots, f_m$ and a polynomial $f$, one can "divide" $f$ by the list to obtain quotients $q_1, \dots, q_m$ and a remainder $r$ such that $f = f_1q_1 + \dots + f_mq_m + r$ (with some particular features), details can be found in books like Cox/Little/O'Shea's Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms. In any case, I am really only concerned about the case where the list is a Gröbner basis, in which case the algorithm can be simplified to: replace the leading term of $f_i$ with the rest of the polynomial whenever that leading terms appears in $f$, and repeat until no terms in $f$ are divisible by leading terms of any $f_i$.
For example, one may reduce $x^2y + 3$ by $f_1 = x - y$ and $f_2 = y^2 - 2$ (lexicographic order) by writing $$x^2y + 3 \xrightarrow{f_1} xy^2 + 3 \xrightarrow{f_1} y^3 + 3 \xrightarrow{f_2} 2y + 3.$$
My question is: Are there upper/lower bounds on the length of this computation? A priori, it seems like it could be pretty long if the polynomials $f_i$ are long, replacing 1 term with many. On the other hand, if for example, $f_1, \dots, f_m$ are all binomials (and let's say we insisted on a graded monomial order, so there are a bounded number of monomials less than any given monomial), then it should be pretty efficient. (Note that the Gröbner basis is part of the input, so the fact that there are doubly-exponentially large Gröbner bases is irrelevant -- the question is really about small Gröbner bases that lead to blow up when you try to use them.)
Also, let me know if this question is more suitable for MathOverflow - I'm not super familiar yet about what kinds of questions go where.
